# Bitstamp - new authentication in C# - signature

Tags: c#, web-services, security, hash, bitcoin

The new authentication of bitstamp says the following:

> Signature is a HMAC-SHA256 encoded message containing: nonce, client ID and API key. The HMAC-SHA256 code must be generated using a secret key that was generated with your API key. This code must be converted to it's hexadecimal representation (64 uppercase characters).Example (Python):
>   message = nonce + client_id + api_key
>   signature = hmac.new(API_SECRET, msg=message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()

Source: [link](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/)

I've got the following code to add the new signature (and other parameters):

```
public void AddApiAuthentication(RestRequest restRequest)
    {
        var nonce = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        var signature = GetSignature(nonce, apiKey, apiSecret, clientId);

        restRequest.AddParameter("key", apiKey);
        restRequest.AddParameter("signature", signature);
        restRequest.AddParameter("nonce", nonce);

    }

    private string GetSignature(long nonce, string key, string secret, string clientId)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", nonce,
            clientId,
            key);

        return ByteArrayToString(SignHMACSHA256(secret, StrinToByteArray(msg))).ToUpper();
    }
    public static byte[] SignHMACSHA256(String key, byte[] data)
    {
        HMACSHA256 hashMaker = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
        return hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
    }

    public static byte[] StrinToByteArray(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] hash)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
```

And then I get this error:

> {"error": "Invalid signature"}

Anyone got an idea what the problem could be? I checked my parameters a 100 times and those aren't wrong. Maybe somebody got a working piece of code (in C#) for the new authentication?

**UPDATE**

Abhinav was right, the StringToByteArray method was wrong (not only the typo :P) the working code is:

```
public static byte[] StrinToByteArray(string str)
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
    }
```

Comment: Curious, what stack do you use for REST?

Comment: @makerofthings7 I use RESTSharp.

Comment: @Julian I'm having a hard time to figure out the bitstamp API, could you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612185/restsharp-bitstamp-authentication-fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `str.ToCharArray()` in `StrinToByteArray` which is incorrect (correct ONLY when used on the same system). You need to use ASCII encoding or something.

Comment: You are my hero! The small change (see update) made the code work. Could also use UTF8 instead of ASCII I noticed after tests.